# Filter rows of VCF file for Match=EXACT?

Tags: vcf, ngs, bash, filtering, data-preprocessing

How do I remove rows in a VCF file on 1kGenome column, where Match=EXACT using bash ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a couple of relevant lines from your .vcf.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter records in Python for example using `pyvcf.VcfFrame.filter_flagany()` [method](https://sbslee-fuc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fuc.api.pyvcf.VcfFrame.filter_flagany) I wrote:

```
>>> from fuc import pyvcf
>>> data = {
...     'CHROM': ['chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1', 'chr1'],
...     'POS': [100, 101, 102, 103],
...     'ID': ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
...     'REF': ['G', 'T', 'A', 'C'],
...     'ALT': ['A', 'C', 'T', 'A'],
...     'QUAL': ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
...     'FILTER': ['.', '.', '.', '.'],
...     'INFO': ['DB', 'DB;H2;Match=EXACT', 'DB;H2;Match=EXACT', '.'],
...     'FORMAT': ['GT', 'GT', 'GT', 'GT'],
...     'Steven': ['0/0', '0/1', '0/1', '0/0'],
... }
>>> vf = pyvcf.VcfFrame.from_dict([], data)
>>> # vf = pyvcf.VcfFrame.from_file('your_vcf.vcf')
>>> vf.df
  CHROM  POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER               INFO FORMAT Steven
0  chr1  100  .   G   A    .      .                 DB     GT    0/0
1  chr1  101  .   T   C    .      .  DB;H2;Match=EXACT     GT    0/1
2  chr1  102  .   A   T    .      .  DB;H2;Match=EXACT     GT    0/1
3  chr1  103  .   C   A    .      .                  .     GT    0/0
>>> vf.filter_flagany(['Match=EXACT'], opposite=True).df
  CHROM  POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO FORMAT Steven
0  chr1  100  .   G   A    .      .   DB     GT    0/0
1  chr1  103  .   C   A    .      .    .     GT    0/0
>>> # vf.to_file('filtered.vcf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing VCF rows, but generally speaking with text files you can use `grep`, if I understand the question:

```
grep -vw "Match=EXACT" file.vcf > filtered.vcf
```